# color ramp texture inbetween points of a curve

Tags: geometry-nodes, bezier-curves, shader-nodes

In Geometry nodes if i have a curve connected to a circle to curve, What would i need to do  texture it in the shading tab is color between each point on the curve? I want to make this plants stem transition to a different color inbetween each of the leaves.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You could use the distance of each point from the origin of the object in the material nodes. If you only want it to change vertically then just use the Z component rather than the RGB to BW coercion done by connecting the vector output to the scalar input as in here.[image]